# File Creation Date Inconsistent Between Windows and Linux

Tags: file-metadata

I need to get the creation date for some files on a network share. When accessing the file on Windows it shows the correct date.

[image: On Windows]

When I switch to Linux and run the stat command on the same file it is different.

```
Birth: 2022-04-06 12:42:10.539775652 -0600
```

How to I get the correct file creation date on Linux?

Comment: What is the underlying filesystem on the server? What os does the server run?

Comment: Did you check the current time in your Linux machine?

Comment: The filesystem of the share is exFAT and the OS is the latest Debian version. The date and time are correct.